# React Testing Library : check if attribute matches regex

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Is there a way with RTL to test if an *element* has a valid *attribute* based on a regex ?

In my case I'd like to check if every `<a>` *tag* has a `href` with *forward* and *trailing slashes* `/` like so : `<a href="/link-1/">Link 1/</a>`

Component :

```
const DropdownMenu = ({ open }) => {
  return (
    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
      {open && (
        <>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link-1/">Link 1</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link-2/">Link 2</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link-3/">Link 3</Link>
          </li>
        </>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Regex : `^\/.*\/$`

Test :

```
 test('links have forward and trailing slashs', () => {
    render(<DropdownMenu open={true}></DropdownMenu>)
    const listLinks = screen.getAllByRole('link')
    listLinks.forEach((el) => {
      expect(el).toHaveAttribute('href', /^\/.*\/$/)
    })
    screen.debug()
  })
```

But Jest doesn't take my regex :

```
-- output :

Expected the element to have attribute:
href=/^\/.*\/$/
Received:
href="/link-1/"
```

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute) for that method?

Comment: Was looking in RTL docs instead. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got it using [`expect.stringMatching(string | regexp)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectstringmatchingstring--regexp)

```
  test('links have beginning and trailing slashes', () => {
    render(<DropdownMenu open={true}></DropdownMenu>)
    const listLinks = screen.getAllByRole('link')
    listLinks.forEach((el) => {
      expect(el).toHaveAttribute('href', expect.stringMatching(/^\/.*\/$/))
    })
    screen.debug()
  })
```